# Problem with Wi-Fi (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) of Please me

Tags: 14.04, wireless

a problem that when turned on the laptop (HP Pavilion G6) Wi-fi was gone I can't include it, tried everything that was, the third day I try to solve this problem, looked for decisions on all possible forums, nothing helped.
What offers are. I need your help. Hi, a problem that when turned on the laptop (HP Pavilion G6) Wi-fi was gone I can't include it, tried everything that was, the third day I try to solve this problem, looked for decisions on all possible forums, nothing helped.
What offers are. I need your help.

At input (rfkill list) it is empty.

```
konstantin@pavilion-g6:~$ rfkill list
konstantin@pavilion-g6:~$ 

konstantin@pavilion-g6:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Network
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
    DeviceName: Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi Adapter
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter [103c:18ec]
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal command `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Network` and the content of `/etc/modprobe.d/bcm4313.conf`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please note:

> ./libkmod/libkmod-config.c:635 kmod_config_parse:
>   /etc/modprobe.d/bcm4313.conf line 1: ignoring bad line starting with
>   ''

As yours is not a bcm4313 device, I'm certain the file is not needed. Please remove it:

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/bcm4313.conf
```

It appears that you compiled a driver for your device that will probably bot solve the problem, as you've seen. Let's blacklist it:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist rt3290sta"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
modprobe -r rt3290sta
exit
```

Now load the correct driver for your device:

```
sudo modprobe rt2800pci
```

If there are any errors, please report them.

In many cases, this driver does not work well with 802.11N. Please change the settings in your router to auto B and G and not auto B, G and N. Now do you connect?

It may take a reboot.

Comment: mistakes in (lspci - knn | grep Net - A2) have disappeared, but there is no Wi-fi all the same  

konstantin@pavilion-g6:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
 DeviceName: Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi Adapter
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter [103c:18ec]

Comment: What does this tell us? `sudo modprobe rt2800pci && dmesg | grep rt2`?

Comment: konstantin@pavilion-g6:~$ sudo modprobe rt2800pci && dmesg | grep rt2
[sudo] пароль для konstantin: 
[   19.418109] register rt2860
[   22.114688] rt2860 0000:07:00.0 rename3: renamed from ra0
[51617.573468] usb usb5-port2: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...

Comment: Please note: *rename3: renamed from ra0* Did you compile another driver, rt3290sta, perhaps? We will need to blacklist it.

Comment: What to me to make?

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few moments.

Comment: At you it has turned out)) Many thanks to you!)